# How to search & replace multiple lines of text in a file that contain a space and represented by a variable?

Tags: bash, shell, perl, sed

I have a file input.txt containing the following text:

```
abc def
ghi jkl
mno pqr
stu vwx
```

I can replace two of the lines in the file with this command:

```
perl -i -p0e 's/ghi jkl\nmno pqr/zyx wvu\ntsr qpo/s' input.txt
```

However, I need for the search and replace strings to be in variables:

```
search_s="ghi jkl\nmno pqr"
replace_s="zyx wvu\ntsr qpo"
```

But now this command doesn't work with the variables:

```
perl -i -p0e 's/'$search_s'/'$replace_s'/s' input.txt
```

I get the error "Substitution pattern not terminated at -e line 1.". The problem seems to be around the spaces in the $search_s variable. I've tried various methods to encode the space to make this work without success.

Note: I'm using a perl command because it handles the search and replace containing a `\n` within a file nicely.  I tried `sed` but not so nice.

Can anyone help me encode the space so it would work in a variable or another command that will perform the search and replace on a file while preserving the `\n`?

Thanks,
Rob

Comment: Word splitting is dividing the arguments. Try `perl -i -p0e "s/$search_s/$replace_s/s"`

Comment: This might mean you also need to double-escape the newlines - `\\n`.

Answer (score 1):

The confusion here is the shell quoting.  When you write

```
perl -i -p0e 's/'$search_s'/'$replace_s'/s' input.txt
```

The shell parses that and calls perl with the following arguments: `-i` `-p03` `s/ghi` `jkl\nmno` `pqr/zyx` `wvu`...
This is not what you want.  This happens because the shell performs word splitting after it expands your variables.  To prevent that, you need to quote the arguments:

```
perl -i -p0e "s/$search_s/$replace_s/s" input.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want to do matching over more than one line, `awk` is interesting.

With awk you can handle this in different ways.
My solution is storing every line in an array and change the stored data when I see,
that I have two matching lines.

```
awk -v line1="ghi jkl" -v line2="mno pqr" '
   {a[NR]=$0}
   $0==line1 {m1=1; next}
   $0==line2 {a[NR-1]="zyx wvu"; a[NR]="tsr qpo"; m1=0}
   END {for (i=1;i<=NR;i++) print a[i]}
   ' input.txt
```

Another solution, without an array, is remembering a first line and print it when the second line doesn't complete a match. With a match, print the replacement strings, and don't forget the `END` statement for printing the last line (when not part of a match).